# Is it possible to export/import Flow types in Node?

Tags: flowtype

What is the correct syntax to export a type definition from a module in Node, and be able to use it?

The [Flow modules types documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/modules/) describes how to export/import types if you are using ES6 modules, but that doesn't work with Node, which uses exports and require().

Answer (score 4):

You can still use `import type ...` and `export type ...` in CommonJS files. They are already custom things added for Flow, they just resemble ES6 module syntax. Since they are all erased by the time the code actually runs, there is no problem.